# Need help understanding explanation about conjugations

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

So my problem asks me to find all subgroups of S3 that are conjugate to {$\rho_{0}, \mu_{2}$}.  The answer key that I am looking at says: "To find all subgroups conjugate to {$\rho_{0}, \mu_{2}$}, we have to pick conjugates from each left coset of {$\rho_{0}, \mu_{2}$}.  It then goes on to list three random permutations. See the link here:

http://www.auburn.edu/~huanghu/math5310/alg-hw-ans-14.pdf

Firstly I have no idea what the problem is doing and why we are picking three random permutations and how these permutations are picked.  I understand the format of the inner automorphism formula but what exactly is this problem trying to accomplish (I mean I can read the problem) but I have no idea what is the point.  Please explain this to someone who is desperately confused with Factor groups.

Comment: What are $\rho_0$ and $\mu_2$?